# How is it that "max(List, key = List.get)" manages to return the correct value?

Tags: python, dictionary, max

I have recently tried to create a function that takes in a string and print out the character with the most number of appearances. I ended up making the string into a dictionary and utilizing something like the code below to search for the character with the most appearances.

```
List = {'7':3, '8':50, '6': 2}
max(List, key = List.get)
```

However, what I don't understand is how the List.get works. How is it interpreted by the computer? What is the logic behind it?
I have tried to do some research by myself but to no avail.
Somebody please help me understand.

Comment: Kinda confusing that `List` is actually a dictionary. Basically `max()` will iterate over `List` which means that every iteration it will receive a *key*, then it will pass this *key* to `List.get()` method which will return a *value* of this *key* so it will be used to obtain maximum item from `List`. Take a look on docs of [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) and [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get).

Comment: `dict.get` return value : [3, 50, 2] then 50 is max. you get '8' base value of 50 .